How to perform split operation on a disjoint set?
I am working on an undirected graph which supports:

addPerson: Inserting a node person.
addRelation: Adding an edge between id1 and id2.
modifyRelation: Modify/Remove an edge between id1 and id2.
isCircle: Check if id1 and id2 are connected.
queryBlockSum: Querying the number of disjoint sets it can be divided into.

public class MyNetwork implements Network {
    /* ... */
    private final DisjointSet disjointSet;

    @Override
    public void addPerson(Person person) {
        /* ... */
        disjointSet.add(person.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void addRelation(int id1, int id2, int value) {
        /* ... */
        disjointSet.merge(id1, id2);
    }

    @Override
    public void modifyRelation(int id1, int id2, int value) {
        /* ... */
        int parent = disjointSet.find(id1);
        if (/* I should remove the edge */) {
            HashSet<Integer> set1 = /* all nodes connected with id1 */;
            HashSet<Integer> set2 = /* all nodes connected with id2 */;
            if (!set1.contains(parent)) {
                disjointSet.resetParent(set1, parent, id1);
            }
            if (!set2.contains(parent)) {
                disjointSet.resetParent(set2, parent, id2);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCircle(int id1, int id2) {
        return disjointSet.find(id1) == disjointSet.find(id2);
    }

    @Override
    public int queryBlockSum() {
        return disjointSet.getSetCount();
    }
}

In order to boost up efficiency, I implemented the disjoint set data structure. It supports:

add: Adding an element x.
find: Finding the parent of an element x (with path compression).
merge: Merge two sets x and y.
split: Change the parents of all elements in c from oldParent to newParent, splitting one set into two. (It is assured that for any element x in c, find(x) == oldParent)
getSetCount: Get the number of sets.

public class DisjointSet {
    private final HashMap<Integer, Integer> parent;
    private int setCount;

    public DisjointSet() {
        this.parent = new HashMap<>();
        this.setCount = 0;
    }

    public int getSetCount() {
        return setCount;
    }

    public void add(int x) {
        parent.put(x, x);
        setCount++;
    }

    public int find(int x) {
        int parentX = parent.get(x);
        if (parentX == x) {
            return x;
        }
        parentX = find(parentX);
        parent.put(x, parentX);
        return parentX;
    }

    public boolean merge(int x, int y) {
        int parentX = find(x);
        int parentY = find(y);
        if (parentX != parentY) {
            parent.put(parentX, parentY);
            setCount--;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void split(Collection<Integer> c, int oldParent, int newParent) {
        for (Integer x : c) {
            parent.put(x, newParent);
        }
        setCount++;
    }
}

The problem is, after merging and splitting multiple times, the disjoint set becomes buggy: I find that two elements are not in the same set (i.e. have different parents), while they are supposed to be. I try to updated the parents of all elements in c before splitting, but it doesn't work:
    public void split(Collection<Integer> c, int oldParent, int newParent) {
        // This doesn't fix the bug.
        for (Integer x : c) {
            find(x);
        }
        for (Integer x : c) {
            parent.put(x, newParent);
        }
        setCount++;
    }

However, if I update the parents of all elements before the split operation, the bug got fixed:
    public void split(Collection<Integer> c, int oldParent, int newParent) {
        // This fixes the bug.
        for (Integer x : parent.keySet()) {
            find(x);
        }
        for (Integer x : c) {
            parent.put(x, newParent);
        }
        setCount++;
    }

I don't understand why I need to update the parents of all elements, even if they don't need to be split.
What is the correct way of performing the split operation on a disjoint set? Or do I have to rebuild the disjoint set because it doesn't support splitting at all?

This cannot work. Imagine that  has  as parent, and  is the collection , but  is not, then calling split on that collection  will not only move  to a new parent, but implicitly also .

Disjoint sets are not suited for solving this sort of problem online. A link cut tree could be used instead.
In its simplest form, link cut trees support Link (add edge), Cut (delete edge), and FindRoot operations, each in amortized O(log N) (where N is the number of nodes). The number of connected components can be easily maintained separately.

The implementation tends to be long, so I will not provide it here.
